# Unresolved reference: bind when building Corda

Tags: corda

In Corda, I was trying to build the network bootstrapper by running the following command:

```
./gradlew buildBootstrapperJar
```

But I got the following error:

```
e: /Users/anon/Documents/corda/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/utilities/ByteArrays.kt: (11, 18): Unresolved reference: bind
e: /Users/anon/Documents/corda/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/utilities/ByteArrays.kt: (179, 39): Unresolved reference: DatatypeConverter
e: /Users/anon/Documents/corda/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/utilities/ByteArrays.kt: (185, 38): Unresolved reference: DatatypeConverter
e: /Users/anon/Documents/corda/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/utilities/EncodingUtils.kt: (11, 18): Unresolved reference: bind
e: /Users/anon/Documents/corda/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/utilities/EncodingUtils.kt: (32, 33): Unresolved reference: DatatypeConverter
e: /Users/anon/Documents/corda/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/utilities/EncodingUtils.kt: (50, 42): Unresolved reference: DatatypeConverter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':core:compileKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally caused by running the wrong JDK version. See the requirements here: https://docs.corda.net/getting-set-up.html#software-requirements.